# Variables in the scopes of a function/module and attributes of the function/module's objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python3, for a function

- Can a variable defined in the local scope of a function **not** be an attribute of the function's function object?
- Conversely, can an attribute of a function's function object **not** be a variable in the local scope of the function

Similarly, for a module:

- Must a variable defined in the global scope of a module be an attribute of the module's module object?
- Conversely, can an attribute of a module's module object   be a variable in the global scope of the module?

Thanks.

Comment: for the second question in both lists it wouldn't be a variable if the attribute name was not usable as a python name/attribute.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "the attribute name was not usable as a python name/attribute"?

Comment: I believe it's possible to create byte code for a function object where the local names array contains python reserved words, and you can do `globals()['for'] = 42` which makes `for` an attribute of the module object, but not a usable variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables and function attributes are completely separate. Each call of a function creates a fresh scope with new, independent local variables, but a function only has one attribute namespace. Locals can be named the same thing as function attributes, but they'll still be distinct and separate.

A module's global variable namespace is its `__dict__`. All module-globals are attributes of the module object and vice versa, unless the attribute is handled by a descriptor; for example, modules have a `__class__` attribute that isn't a global, because `__class__` is handled by a descriptor.

Comment: Thanks. In the global scope of a module, do `globals()`, `__dict__` and `dir()` provide the same list of objects?